# java - execute commands in chroot

Tags: java, chroot

I have a python script that runs some scripts and commands against a chroot that and I would like to migrate it to Java.

In python, to work on the chroot, I am doing the following:

```
os.chdir(root)
os.chroot(root)
```

And, then when I'm done, I'm doing:

```
os.fchdir(real_root)
os.chroot('.')
os.close(real_root)
```

Whenever I execute any commands in python, they're executed against the chroot and I'd like to do the same in Java.

Is this possible, what facilities would I need to use to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I am doing it isn't fancy, but it works.  Is there a better solution?

```
1. mount all filesystems
2. run chroot some-shell
3. use expect library (or something equivalent)
4. unmount filesystems
```